# The page failed to load my scripts module after finishing to load

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I create the script tag and append it on the document with the event of loading so that the page when finishes to load it will execute my script but i'm i'm facing with the problem where the page didn't load my script and didn't drop the error to my scripts code looks like this

```
window.addEventListener('load',() => {
        script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'module';
        script.src = 'custom.js';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    });
```

but i doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check up if you are doing this over local host connection because the module didn't run without the connection or you the problem might be in your browse if you are using IE 7 or earlier but the solution of the IE 7 or earlier is this

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.onload = scriptFunction();
    } else if (window.attachEvent){
        window.onload = scriptFunction();
    }
    function scriptFunction() {
        script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'module';
        script.src = 'custom.js';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
```